How to convert dragGesture value to CGPoint in SwiftUI?
I have an array of defined points, and I'm using these points to draw a star at each location. The star view should simply report back the drag gesture for updating each point's position. Currently, the code works partially: the drag amount is not equal to the displacement of the stars.
My goal is to keep the star view as minimal as possible; I only want to use this view to read the drag amount. I would like the points' positions to be updated within a ForEach loop. How can I correctly convert the DragGesture value to a CGPoint in the ForEach to achieve this?

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var points: [CustomPoint] = [CustomPoint(x: 100, y: 100), CustomPoint(x: 200, y: 200), CustomPoint(x: 300, y: 100)]
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            
            Color.blue
            
            ForEach($points) { $point in
                
                DrawStarView(customPoint: point) { value in
                    point.cgPointValue = CGPoint(x: point.cgPointValue.x + value.width, y: point.cgPointValue.y + value.height)
                }
                
            }
            
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct CustomPoint: Identifiable {
    
    init(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) {
        self.cgPointValue = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }

    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var cgPointValue: CGPoint
}


struct DrawStarView: View {
    
    init(customPoint: CustomPoint, action: @escaping (CGSize) -> Void) {
        self.customPoint = customPoint
        self.action = action
    }
    
    let customPoint: CustomPoint
    let action: (CGSize) -> Void
    
    
    var body: some View {
                
        return createStarPath(at: customPoint.cgPointValue)
            .fill(Color.white)
            .shadow(radius: 5)
            .gesture(dragGesture)
        
    }

    func createStarPath(at point: CGPoint, size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)) -> Path {
        let outerRadius = size.width / 2
        let innerRadius = outerRadius / 2.5
        let center = point
        let pointsOnStar = 5
        let angleIncrement = .pi * 2 / CGFloat(pointsOnStar * 2)
        
        var path = Path()
        
        for i in 0..<pointsOnStar * 2 {
            let angle = angleIncrement * CGFloat(i) - .pi / 2
            let radius = (i % 2 == 0) ? outerRadius : innerRadius
            let x = center.x + radius * cos(angle)
            let y = center.y + radius * sin(angle)
            
            if i == 0 {
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
            } else {
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
            }
        }
        
        path.closeSubpath()
        return path
    }

    private var dragGesture: some Gesture {
        
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
            .onChanged { value in
                action(value.translation)
            }
            .onEnded { value in
                action(value.translation)
            }
        
    }

}


This is a very weird way of doing things. Why not just use position to position the stars? And make each star a Shape

I have pre defind points, I am using points system to get red of dealing with position or offset.

Why don't you want to deal with position? This sounds like an XY Problem.

Because I have points and using GeometryReader, adding position is not needed here, because I am drawing at the point I want, just for remembering, I have no issue with drawing(no need for position or offset), as you see it draws fine, the issue is about drag.

My point is that drawing stars at specific points using a Path makes this a lot more difficult than it needs to be. Are you open to the idea of using position to position the stars, and making a Shape that represents a star?

I've done extensive testing, and this approach is the best in my code. Using position would make it very difficult to maintain the final points' positions in the array. My current method avoids these issues entirely. Why do you think the drag issue is connected to using or not using the position modifier? The idea behind my code is to update the point precisely by the amount of drag, so that shouldn’t make a big difference that would require me to use position. I can resolve the issue with either position or offset; the goal is to convert the drag (dx and dy) into accurate point displacement.

I did not think "the drag issue is connected to using or not using the position modifier". I never said that. I highly doubt that "using position would make it very difficult to maintain the final points' positions in the array". DrawStarView should just take a Binding<CGPoint> and update that.

But as you can see in code, since I can draw at any point I wish, why do I need position modifier? I did not looked for this claim that I am going to say: I think SwiftUI position modifier or offset modifier must be using the coding way in my question in background, because all we got in SwiftUI is area(size) and points in view

I am also having a hard time understanding the reasons behind this approach. From what I can tell, you're rebelling against the SwiftUI way by tying the star shape with its position and size, instead of keeping everything separate (and more reusable). With your approach, you can't control the size of a star using the frame modifier, for example. If you were to use position and a binding, the final position of the points in the array would be the very points themselves, so there would be nothing to maintain other than reading the values. I'll post an answer to show it.

@Sweeper I added an answer and I am curious if it aligns more with the direction you were suggesting above.

translation is the total translation since the gesture has started. It is not the difference between the location between this call to onChange and the next call to onChange.
If the difference is what you want, you should track the previous translation using a separate @State, and subtract that from the current translation, and pass that into action.
@State var lastTranslation: CGSize = .zero

private var dragGesture: some Gesture {
    
    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
        .onChanged { value in
            action(.init(
                width: value.translation.width - lastTranslation.width,
                height: value.translation.height - lastTranslation.height)
            )
            lastTranslation = value.translation
        }
        .onEnded { value in
            action(.init(
                width: value.translation.width - lastTranslation.width,
                height: value.translation.height - lastTranslation.height)
            )
            lastTranslation = .zero
        }
    
}


As mentioned in the comments, it is difficult to follow the logic behind the OP's approach, as it doesn't offer additional advantages nor simplify things in any way that I can tell.
Since @Sweeper provided the solution for fixing the drag gesture (incorporated with some minor changes in the example below), here's how the same functionality could be achieved in a more SwiftUI way and more along the lines of what I believe @Sweeper was suggesting in earlier comments.
Some additional notes:

The star view (DrawStarView in your original code) shouldn't need an action closure to make everything work, given it already receives the point as a parameter. It makes everything unnecessarily convoluted.

The createStarPath func in your code is basically the code of a star shape, so it should be turned into a shape to make it reusable instead of existing only inside the DrawStarView view.

The overall complexity of various initializers and action closures is simply unnecessary - compare with the code below.

The GeometryReader is not used, so it was replaced with a ZStack to make layout and logic more intuitive.

Added a button that prints the (updated) star position to the console in order to show that there is no maintenance of final points position, since the the points get updated directly in the array, thanks to the binding passed to StarView.

Added an optional double tap on star to reset its position, for convenience.

Note that the size of the stars can be controlled using the .frame modifier, which wasn't possible previously. If needed, additional parameters could be added to StarView for dynamically controlling the star size. UPDATE: I went ahead and added a size property to CustomPoint that allows to set the star size now.


Here's the full code:
import SwiftUI

struct StarDragGesture: View {
    
    //State values
    @State private var points: [CustomPoint] = [CustomPoint(x: 100, y: 100), CustomPoint(x: 200, y: 200, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)), CustomPoint(x: 300, y: 100)]
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            //Background color
            Color.blue
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            //Display a star for every point in the points array, at the specified position
            ForEach($points) { $point in
                StarView(position: $point)
            }
            
            //Button for checking the updated star positions in the console
            Button {
                print("-----")
                for (index, point) in points.enumerated() {
                    print("Point \(index + 1) - X: \(point.x), Y: \(point.y)")
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Check positions")
                    .foregroundStyle(.blue)
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            .tint(.white)
            
        }
        
    }
}

struct StarView: View {
    
    //Parameters
    @Binding var position: CustomPoint
    
    //State values
    @State private var lastTranslation: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var initialPosition: CustomPoint?
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        
        StarShape(points: 5, innerRatio: 0.4)
            .fill(Color.white)
            .shadow(radius: 5)
            .frame(width: position.size.width, height: position.size.height)
            .position(position.coordinates)
        
            //Reset star position on double tab
            .onTapGesture(count: 2) {
                if let initialPosition {
                    position = initialPosition
                }
            }
            .gesture(dragGesture)
        
            //Optional - Capture initial position for resetting
            .onAppear {
                initialPosition = position
            }
        
    }
    
    private var dragGesture: some Gesture {
        
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
            .onChanged { value in
                updatePosition(value.translation)
                lastTranslation = value.translation
            }
            .onEnded { value in
                updatePosition(value.translation)
                lastTranslation = .zero
            }
    }
    
    //Helper function for updating the position based on gesture translation
    private func updatePosition(_ translation: CGSize ) {
        position.x += translation.width - lastTranslation.width
        position.y += translation.height - lastTranslation.height
    }
    
}

struct StarShape: Shape {
    var points: Int = 5
    var innerRatio: CGFloat = 0.5  // Adjusts the depth of the star's inner points
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        guard points >= 2 else { return Path() }
        
        let center = CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2, y: rect.height / 2)
        let angle = 2 * .pi / CGFloat(points)
        let radius = min(rect.width, rect.height) / 2
        
        var path = Path()
        let startAngle = -CGFloat.pi / 2
        
        for i in 0..<points * 2 {
            let rotationAngle = startAngle + angle * CGFloat(i) / 2
            let pointRadius = i % 2 == 0 ? radius : radius * innerRatio
            let x = center.x + pointRadius * cos(rotationAngle)
            let y = center.y + pointRadius * sin(rotationAngle)
            
            if i == 0 {
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
            } else {
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
            }
        }
        
        path.closeSubpath()
        return path
    }
}

struct CustomPoint: Identifiable {
    
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var x: CGFloat
    var y: CGFloat
    
    //Computed properties
    var coordinates: CGPoint {
        CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }
    
    //Optional property for possibly creating stars of various sizes
    var size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
}

#Preview {
    StarDragGesture()
}

Give this a try and let me know if it makes sense or if it still makes things difficult for your use case.

Yes, from quick skim, this is what I was trying to suggest in the comments.

Thanks for code but the answer of @Sweeper was what I was looking.

No problem, just wanted to put this out there for future reference.
